# How to change body background dynamically when navigate to different components in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, background-color

For example, if we have two components like "home page" component and "contacts page" component. When I load home page component, body background should be red, when navigate to contacts page component the body background should be in blue.

Comment: I tried to add background color for body tag on each component&#39;s CSS file . Like 
body {
Background-color: red;
}

But it doesn&#39;t work properly. The background color CSS property gets override on other components too. For e.g if I load home component , it has background red, if I navigate to contacts component it Changed into blue. If I again navigate back to home component it remains blue. It doesn&#39;t changed.

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr to mimic what you currently have in place so we can help you.

Comment: You can use ngClass to achieve this.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain could you please explain with sample code?